# I need REGEX For Simplified Chinese Characters

Tags: angular

I need REGEX For Simplified Chinese Characters- 中国哲学书电子化计划 For a Angular Project
The Input should only allow Simplied Chinese Text Not any other thing

i tried with regex  this.selectedCountryValidator = '^[/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/]';

but this does not work

Comment: I need lots of things also but SO is not a code writing service. Please post what you have tried, any errors, and output generated.

Comment: I have a input field which should allow only simplified chinese characters

Comment: i tried with regex this.selectedCountryValidator = '^[/[\u3400-\u9FBF]/]';

but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex `^\p{Han}+$` or this `^[\u4E00-\u9FCC]+$`. It's allows to input only at least 1 character of Simplified Chinese Text